# Adding more elements to a GridView using adapters in Android

Tags: java, android, adapter

This is the desired output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3xgw.jpg

So basically, I'm using a GridView to generate all those 18 buttons and I am trying to add some TextViews on top of every Button, and 2 on the bottom side of the last buttons.

This is my Adapter implementation:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by pop on 9/15/2014.
 */
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private String[] _items;
    LayoutInflater _inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        this._context = context;
        this._items = items;
        _inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return _items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell_time, null);
        }
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
        button.setText(_items[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My gridcell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/wampWhite"
        android:background="@drawable/time_input_button_selector"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="\u2713"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Java file using these two:

```
public class TimeActivity extends Activity  {

    private GridView gridView;
    private final String[] items = new String[] {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);
        setFonts();

        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.timeInputView);
        CustomGridAdapter adapter = new CustomGridAdapter(TimeActivity.this, items);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.time, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setFonts() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        TextView dateOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateOutput);
        dateOutput.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

I tried adding in the gridcell a TextView, and afterwards giving it android:layout_above(id of buttons) but it was just inside the button, on the top side of it. Any suggestions? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get your RelativeLayout to look like you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:padding="4dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridcell_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="6:00" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/gridcell_time"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/wampWhite"
    android:background="@drawable/time_input_button_selector"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="\u2713" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All I've done is added the TextView before the ToggleButton and set the TextView's `layout_centerHorizontal` property to `true`. I also changed the `below` property of the ToggleButton to the id of the TextView (in this case I called it `gridcell_time`).

Comment: will try it out and let you know asap! till then, cheers for the answer! :) @bwegs

Answer (score 0):

@bwegs - It works, thanks a lot! The only problem right now is that I have 18 buttons and need 21 TextViews.

As I mentioned above, each button has a textView on top of it, but the last buttons from the bottom, have 3 textViews below the buttons. Due to my implementation, I'm not really sure how will I add those 3 textViews...

Comment: What if you add those TextViews below the ToggleButton in the layout I have above like so:             `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/calendar_day_gridcell"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                               android:text="TextView" />`

Comment: @bwegs - indeed, it's ok :) but problem is I only want 3 of these TextViews for the 3 bottom buttons I have. This one will apply for every button in the list. With my implementation of the adapter, as you can see, I use a String[] to add the text to every TextView.

I could do that again, another array, and for 15 elements just leave the string as this "" while the last 3 one with the actual hours. But I think this would overwrite the previous array with hours for the rest of the elements in the textView.

Comment: Have you considered creating a new xml file to handle these 3 different buttons?

Comment: Problem is buttons are generated using the adapter, not really sure how would I handle those 3 ones only :) Could you be a bit more explicit, please?

Comment: It's a question of how you want to use the `visibility` property. It might be easiest to add the 2nd TextView to your layout file for every button that is created and then hide all the 2nd TextView's that you don't want to display by setting the `visibility` property of those TextViews to `GONE`. Does that make sense?

Comment: True, but as you see, the way I'm adding the text for the TextViews is within the String arrays. If you check the getView method, I only have one index in there, int position, that I use to add the text for buttons or text views. I could, of course, create another array.. and hide whatever elements I don't want to output but I think this might overwrite the values from the previous String array, if you know what I mean

Comment: For this implementation you'd need to add an `if` statement in your getView method that handles every text item before those last 3 elements (for example something like `if(position < 17)`) and then the `else` condition will handle the last 3 'special' cases.

Comment: there is a problem though with this, since I only can use one index , which is int position, and that is for 18 elements only :) since I need no more than 18, I can't work with this one @bwegs